# Validating Access Token in ASP.NET Core Web API project

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two applications: one is an ASP.NET Core Web API and the other is a Maui Blazor application.

I successfully logged into Azure using `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` with my client ID. However, I'm encountering an issue with the access token.

I want to utilize the same access token that I obtained and send it to my API project for authentication. Is this achievable? If so, could someone provide me with an example of how to configure the `program.cs` file in the API project to validate the access token?

Comment: This sample should give you some pointers: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/ebdcffe9b68553dc988f8df902c226c3ce250fc9/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph/TodoListService/Startup.cs#L25. If you only need to validate access tokens and not call any other APIs from the API, then you only need `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)`. Check the appsettings files to see what they configure as well.